# How to make the debugger use "make" in VSCode for C/C++ files. What parameters should I add/change in tasks.json or launch.json?

Tags: visual-studio-code, gnu-make, vscode-debugger

I had to use an external library which is not inbuilt in gcc, which needs linking manually every time I compile. So I changed some environment variables in order for it to work properly with **make filename**. But VSCode debugger uses gcc so it doesn't debug. So I want to change it to use **make**.

Comment: Have you tried editing tasks.json [like this](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/cppblog/building-your-c-application-with-visual-studio-code/#Makefiles)?